# 'D:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command.. pysparse

Tags: python, windows, command-line, anaconda

I have been trying to install csc-pysparse, however I get the following error:

```
'D:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable 
 program or batch file.

error: Command "gcc -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DLENFUNC_OK=1 -
DNPY_MINGW_USE_CUSTOM_MSVCR -D__MSVCRT_VERSION__=0x0900 -Ipysparse\sparse\src 
-I"D:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" 
-I"D:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" 
-ID:\Pyt\csc-pysparse-1.1.1.4\csc-pysparse-1.1.1.4\pysparse\include 
-I"D:\Program Files\Anaconda\include" 
-I"D:\Program Files\Anaconda\PC" -c pysparse\sparse\src\spmatrixmodule.c 
-o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pysparse\sparse\src\spmatrixmodule.o" 
failed with exit status 1
```

I do understand it comes from the fact that "D:\Program Files\" has to be put in quotes, however can I somehow figure out which file is it that I have to fix? Is there anything I can do?

I tried to use `pip install` before and the result was the same. The command I am using currently is `python setup.py install` from csc-pysparse directory.

Comment: As a temporary workaround, can you install Anaconda in c:\Anaconda instead?

Comment: Are you installing this using `pip`?  Or `easy_install`? Which tool are you using, because that will have a big impact upon where you need to edit.

Comment: If you find the [wheel](http://wheel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/story.html) file that `pip` downloaded for the install, you should be able to open it and find whichever file is generating that `gcc` call.  It isn't as easy as [@Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'s suggestion, but it is "something you can do".

Comment: Is there any way I could pull that name from the install log in the command line?